# Django 1.3, extending to User auth system, User Profiling or Subclassing?

Tags: python, django, profiling, subclass

Subclassing:
http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

User Profiling:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

Which one is more efficient and less of a hassle?

And

Which way should I go if I plan to scale big?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use subclassing unless you're prepared to 1) write your own auth backend, and 2) forgo ever using a different auth backend.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to makes sense to have the simplest model possible for authentication and then all other connected data in the Profile.

Generally I would use the UserProfile class for reasons such as Ignacio says but also because after a bout of normalisation, I normally find the data wouldn't belong in the User table.